# pandas to_sql() replace table but keep column names

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Hello I want to write my pandas dataframe to a postgresql table. I want to use the existing DB schema as well.

I am doing:

```
df = pd.read_csv("ss.csv")

table_name = "some_name"
engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/databasename")

df.to_sql(table_name,engine, schema="public",if_exists='replace',index=False)
```

This however, replaces the whole table including the column name provided by schema. I want to update the content of table but keep the column names.

Even when I tried `if_exists='replace'`, I get "column of relation does not exist" because in the schema the column is named `timestamp` but the `df` as `Timestamp`

Comment: Would your problem be solved if you simply forced the column names in the DataFrame to be all lower case?

Comment: no, there are other columns with mismatching names. For example, `_` instead of  `-` or  `space`

Comment: Get column names from existing table, and set them on `df.columns = columns` to match those before the `db.to_sql(...)` call.

Comment: That is what I am doing at the moment. I thought there would be a direct way. Thanks ayway